# Can't create a Windows Form in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, windows, forms, visual-studio-2015

Okay, so. When I open Visual Studio 2015 and create an Empty CLR project under C++, then create a Windows Form, it says *Opening file...*. :
[Then it shows me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mPyc.png)

By the way, I use Visual Studio 2015 and not 2017 because it just doesnt open the Windows form, when I press create or open file, nothing happens, the UI disappears then comes back [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vu6r.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Dont give your project the name of a file. You are naming your project "Project.h". Why?